# pyspark 2 csv read quote is ignored

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
tx = 'a,b,c,"[""d"", ""e""]""'
file=open('temp.csv','wt')
file.writelines(tx)
file.close()


sparkSession.read.csv('temp.csv', quote='"').show()
+---+---+---+-------+---------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|    _c3|      _c4|
+---+---+---+-------+---------+
|  a|  b|  c|"[""d""| ""e""]""|
+---+---+---+-------+---------+
```

Where the desired output is

```
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|    _c3            |
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|"[""d"", ""e""]""| |
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PySpark, but there seems to be something wrong with the quotes (one too many) - should probably be:

```
'a,b,c,"[""d"", ""e""]"'
```

and the output should then be:

```
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|    _c3            |
+---+---+---+-------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|["d", "e"]         |
+---+---+---+-------------------+
```